# How to extract longer strings and ignore sub-strings from given sentence?

Tags: python-3.x, string-matching

I have a list of strings and a sentence as follows:

```
list_of_strings=["skin allergy","hair loss","allergy","hair", "skin"]

sentence="She experienced skin allergy and hair loss after using it for 2-3 weeks"
```

and I want to match `list_of_strings` to the `sentence` and print output as only longer phrase (ignoring substring):

```
skin allergy
hair loss
```

I wrote this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836195/comparing-data-using-lookup-and-output-only-longest-phrase-in-the-data-using-pyt): But this extracts everything that matches.

Comment: Don't provide external links, use text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

list_of_strings=["skin allergy","hair loss","allergy","hair", "skin"]
sentence="She experienced skin allergy and hair loss after using it for 2-3 weeks"
pattern = re.compile(r"(\b" + "|".join(list_of_strings) + r")\b")

m = pattern.findall(sentence)
print(m)
```

**Output:**

```
['skin allergy', 'hair loss']
```